# React: How to call hooks

Tags: reactjs, arrays, react-hooks

In my project, want to add chips for the email field. For that purpose, the following component is added to the chips.js

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { useState, useEffect, useMemo } from 'react';
import { Badge, Button, Form } from 'react-bootstrap';
const Chips = ({ pattern, chips, placeholder, save, maxlength, title, forwardedRef }) => {
    const [newChips, setNewChips] = useState(chips);

    if (!chips || typeof chips !== 'object') {
        return null;
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        save(newChips);
    }, [newChips]);

    const getObjKeyName = (obj) => {
        if (obj && typeof obj === 'object') {
            return Object.keys(obj)[0];
        }
    };
    const removeChip = (evt, selectedChip) => {
        const key = getObjKeyName(selectedChip);
        const selectedChips = newChips.filter((chip) => chip[key] !== selectedChip[key]);
        setNewChips(selectedChips);
        evt.preventDefault();
    };

    const renderChips = (chips) => {
        if (chips?.length === 0) return;
        const renderElem = chips?.map((chip, index) => {
            const key = getObjKeyName(chip);

            return (
                <Button variant={chip.valid ? 'primary' : 'secondary'} key={index}>
                    {chip[key]}

                    <Badge variant='secondary' style={{ backgroundColor: 'white', color: 'black', marginLeft: '10px' }} onClick={(evt) => removeChip(evt, chip)}>
                        x
                    </Badge>
                </Button>
            );
        });

        return renderElem;
    };

    const updateChips = (evt) => {
        let currentVal = evt.current ? evt.current.value : evt.target.value;
        if (currentVal === '') return;

        // Todo

        setNewChips((newChips) => [...newChips, { email: currentVal, valid: pattern.test(currentVal) }]);
        forwardedRef.current.value = '';

        save(newChips);
    };
    const handleChange = (evt) => {
        if (evt.which === 13) {
            evt.preventDefault();
            updateChips(evt);
        }
    };
    const validChips = newChips?.filter((chip) => chip.valid === true);
    const memoRenderChips = useMemo(() => renderChips(newChips), [newChips]);
    return (
        <div>
            <Form.Group className='mb-3' controlId=''>
                <Form.Label style={{ display: 'block' }}>{title}</Form.Label>
                {memoRenderChips}
                <div style={{ display: 'flex' }}>
                    <Form.Control type='text' style={{ display: 'inline-block', marginRight: '10px' }} placeholder={placeholder} name='sender' onKeyDown={handleChange} maxLength={maxlength} required={validChips.length === 0} ref={forwardedRef} />
                    <Button onClick={() => updateChips(forwardedRef)}> Add </Button>
                </div>
            </Form.Group>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Chips;

Chips.propTypes = {
    pattern: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    chips: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    placeholder: PropTypes.string,
    saved: PropTypes.func,
};

Chips.defaultProps = {
    limit: 10,
    maxlength: 50,
};
```

but it causes the following error

[image]

I analyzed some StackOverflow solutions, I am a beginner in reactjs so I don't know how to apply them here, so please share your valuable suggestions to solve this problem.

Also suggest other packages that can be used instead of "react-email-chips".

Comment: You are returning before calling `useEffect` and `useMemo`. You have to first call all the hooks, then you can return

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hooks must be called on the top level of our components.
Error in console says the solution also.
You are trying to return before hooks. Below return code is called before hooks:

```
if (!chips || typeof chips !== 'object') {
    return null;
}
```

make sure you dont return the component function before any hooks.

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html check this for reference.